# Firefox "Search with..." on highlighted text: How to open new tab in background?

Tags: firefox

My firefox is set in the about:config to open new tabs in the background, i.e. it doesn't change focus from the tab I opened it from. This setting does not affect the behavior when I search highlighted text from the right click (context) menu however; how I do make it so?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly to open a new tab and bring focus immediately for the Search field, I set mine like this:

Open about:config and find the following:

browser.search.openintab | Set to true

browser.search.context.loadInBackground | Set or make sure it is set to false

Now, when I enter any search terms by typing or pasting then Enter or right-click and then left-click on the drop-down menu item, "Paste & Search", my new tab is switched to immediately.

For opening links in a new tab where it is switched to immediately (brought into focus) from email links (left-click only) or webpage links where you probably are holding down the Ctrl key and clicking or using mouse wheel---where other tabs are already opened---you need to go to Tools>Options>General>Tabs and check the boxes for both "Open links in tabs instead of new windows" and "When you open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately". You also might try Shift+click. Seems to work in most browsers.

I hope I understood what you wanted and explained what I did clearly enough.

Answer (score -1):

In about:config, set:

```
browser.search.context.loadInBackground
```

to

```
true
```